# How to set check order for JSR303 bean validation

Tags: validation, bean-validation

I use the JSR303 Bean Validation to check the form input.

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 4, max = 30)
private String name;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 100)
@Email
private String mail;
```

when then name = '' and email = ''，the @NotBlank, @Size at name, @NotBlank, 
@Size, @Email at mail will be checked.

I want set the check order,  when the previous order is invalid, the next is not checked, for example.

```
@NotBlank(order = 1)
@Size(min = 4, max = 30, order = 2)
private String name;
```

(above is not support by JSR303)

is there a way to implement it for using JSR303? 
(i think the custom annotation will done, but i don't like to add a custom annotation for every property)

And I also consider the validation group and group sequence, but i think there are some difference for my need.

```
@NotBlank(groups = First.class)
@Size(min = 4, max = 30, groups = Second.class)
private String name;

@NotBlank(groups = First.class)
@Size(max = 100, groups = Second.class)
@Email(groups = Third.class)
private String mail;
```

When the name is blank and the mail is "abc". Only the @NotBlank at name, and @NotBlank at mail will be checked by JSR303, Because the @NotBlank at name is invalid, so the Second and Third group is not be checked.

But my need is @NotBlank at name and @NotBlank, @Size, @Email at mail should be checked. Because the @NotBlank at name is invalid, so the @Size at name is not be checked, and the @NotBlank,@Size at mail is valid, so the @Email at mail is be checked.

Perhaps, the below pseudocode will be clear to describe my requirement.

```
// retrieves all fields and check one by one.
for (Field field : fields) {
  List annotations = getJsr303Annotations(field);
  // retrieves all annotations on field and check one by one.
  for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
    CheckResult result = check(annotation, field);
    if (result.isValid()) {
       continue;
    } else {
       errors.add(result);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a good way to implement my requirement by JSR303?

Answer (score 6):

Yes Bean Validation supports this feature. It is called validation groups and group sequences. Groups are simple marker interfaces, for example you could create the two interfaces *First* and *Second* and change your code to something like this:

```
@NotBlank(groups = First.class)
@Size(min = 4, max = 30, groups = Second.class)
private String name;
```

Then you can define a group sequence:

```
@GroupSequence({ First.class, Second.class})
interface All {
}
```

Get hold of the **Validator** and call validator.validate(myObject, All.class)

It's all in the documentation.

Comment: Very thank you for your reply, group sequence is do not meet my need, i edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to define two sequences. One for *name* and one for *mail*?

```
@GroupSequence({NameFirst.class, NameSecond.class})
interface AllName {
}

@GroupSequence({MailFirst.class, MailSecond.class, MailThird.class})
interface AllMail {
}
```

In this case you would call the validator like this:

```
validator.validate(myObject, AllName.class, AllMail.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of validation related annotations / constraints cannot be specified at time of writing this answer. I've submitted order related issue to Hibernate Validator team a time ago, the issue was was accepted and probably will be solved in a next Bean Validation specification release - see more details here: http://beanvalidation.org/proposals/BVAL-248/ Btw, in simple cases you can avoid "order conflict" by using "non conflicting" combinations of annotations, e.g. `NotNull` and `Size` - Size will evaluate to true for `null` value.