# How to validate till the first violation using hibernate validator

Tags: validation, hibernate-validator

I am new to using hibernate validator. I just want to know if there is a way to stop further validations when I get the first violation. 
For example consider my case below.

public class CustomerDetails {

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=10, max=10)
private String CustomerID;


@NotNull
private String customerName;

@NotNull
@Pattern([0-9]*)
private String phoneNumber;
```

}

What I want to accomplish, is to make the validator to stop validating the other fields if the first field "CustomerID" itself is invalid. If the customerID is valid, we proceed to validate the next field customerName. In case that is not valid, the validator must stop there and not validate further. What I am concerned about is the performance. If my bean under test has 100 fields, will it not impact performance to validate all the 100 if the first one itself is not valid and I can display only one error to my end user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set check order for JSR303 bean validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827508/how-to-set-check-order-for-jsr303-bean-validation)

Comment: @Hardy Check order talks about the order of each field. Here all the fields will be validated till the first violation of that particular field occurs. What I am trying to accomplish, is if one constraint of one field fails, the remaining fields should not be validated henceforth. My project allows me to throw only one field error to end user. Validating all 100 fields may hamper performance when the 1st field itself fails. When field 1 has a violation, field 2,3,4...100 should never get validated. Is this possible in JSR?