# Order of constraint validation - Jersey

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API.

I have annotated my resource with a built-in constraint and a user-defined constraint.

```
@Path("myPath")
public class MyResource
{
    @NotEmpty
    @AssertBoolean
    @FormParam("my-param")
    private String m_myParam;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public Response test(String body) throws Exception
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

My user-defined constraint, `@AssertBoolean`, checks that the value of the parameter is either `true` or `false`.

When I submit a `POST` request without providing a value for `my-param` I get an exception in the validator for `@AssertBoolean` because the value of the parameter is `null`. This means that it is validating `@AssertBoolean` before `@NotEmpty`.

Can I force an order on the validation? Or will I have to check for `null` in my validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a question regarding the ordering of Bean Validation constraints since JAX-RS relies on the Bean Validation spec and Jersey relies on the implementation provided by hibernate-validator.

To evaluate constraint annotations in their order would require that java.lang.reflect.Field allows to retrieve the annotations in their declaration order. The actual behaviour seems to be [not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222541/3215527).

Then take a look at this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28388265/3215527): It states that explicit ordering of bean validation constraints is not supported right now and links to a proposal which would allow that.

Another point to consider is that bean validation does not stop when a single constraint fails, since it allows to accumulate error messages from different constraints.

Therefore to solve your problem simply incorporate a null check in your AssertBoolean implementation.